# How to change font size in ggcuminc

Tags: r, ggplot2, survival

I am plotting a cumulative incidence plot of a competing risk model using the [tidycmprsk](https://mskcc-epi-bio.github.io/tidycmprsk/) package.  I'd like to increase the font size of everything - the x and y axis tick labels, the legend, the p-value, and the legend of the risk table.  How do I do that?

Here's what I currently have:

```
library(tidycmprsk)
library(ggsurvfit)

cuminc(Surv(ttdeath, death_cr) ~ trt, trial) %>%
  ggcuminc() +
  add_confidence_interval() +
  add_risktable(size=5) + 
  scale_y_continuous(
    limits = c(0, 0.5),
    labels = scales::percent) +
  labs(title="Cumulative Risk of Cancer",
       x = "Time (years)") +
  add_pvalue(location="caption") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 25))
```

Comment: Add `theme_gray(base_size = 16)` to your plot.